# Assign promise to Interface in Angular 7

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get the value's from a object in Angular 7.

I'm receiving the data from the following http get call in the service class:

```
  async getSelectedRatecard(id: number): Promise<Ratecard> {
      return await this.http.get<Ratecard>('http://localhost:8080//shipmentRate/' + id)
      .toPromise();
  }
```

So this call returns a promise.
I use this promise in the following call:

```
 setCarrier(id: number){
    this.selectedRatecard = this.ratecardService.getSelectedRatecard(id);
    this.updateCurrentValue();
  }
```

Right now, the type of selectedRatecard is any:

```
selectedRatecard: any;
```

My goal is that selectedRatecard is of type Ratecard, which is an interface:

```
export interface Ratecard{

    carrierId: number,
    ucarrierName: string,
    customsClearanceCosts: number,
    flegtSurcharge: number,
    hsCodeCharge: number,
    provisionForPrePaidDutiesFactor: number,
     prepaidCustomsDuty: number,
     deliveryOrder: number,
     inspectionCharges: number,
     lsps20feet: number,
     lsps40feet: number,
     lastmileCtvrede: number,
     ocmFee: number
```

}

The reason i want to do this is because right now I can not annotate with for example `this.selectedRatecard[carrierId]`. This will get me undefined printed.

When I console.log(this.selectedRatecard) the following is printed:

```
ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}
__zone_symbol__state: true
__zone_symbol__value:
carrierId: 3
carrierName: "Hapag-Lloyd Rotterdam"
customsClearanceCosts: 68
deliveryOrder: 40
flegtSurcharge: 55
hsCodeCharge: null
inspectionCharges: 15
lastmileCtvrede: 94
lsps20feet: 15
lsps40feet: 15
ocmFee: 100
prepaidCustomsDuty: null
provisionForPrePaidDutiesFactor: null
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

But I want this printed in the following way so I can acces values in the object.
This is wat gets returned by the http get call in Postman:

```
{
    "carrierId": 3,
    "carrierName": "Hapag-Lloyd Rotterdam",
    "customsClearanceCosts": 68.0,
    "flegtSurcharge": 55.0,
    "hsCodeCharge": null,
    "provisionForPrePaidDutiesFactor": null,
    "prepaidCustomsDuty": null,
    "deliveryOrder": 40.0,
    "inspectionCharges": 15.0,
    "lsps20feet": 15.0,
    "lsps40feet": 15.0,
    "lastmileCtvrede": 94.0,
    "ocmFee": 100.0
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options-

## Option 1 (Using `.then` callback)

```js
setCarrier(id: number) {
    this.ratecardService.getSelectedRatecard(id).then(data => {
            this.selectedRatecard = data;
            this.updateCurrentValue();
    });
}
```

## Options 2 (Using `async-await`)

```js
async setCarrier(id: number) {
    this.selectedRatecard = await this.ratecardService.getSelectedRatecard(id);
    this.updateCurrentValue();
}
```

---

## Improvements

By the way, you don't need `async-await` in your service method. You can simply return promise-

```js
getSelectedRatecard(id: number): Promise<Ratecard> {
    return this.http
            .get<Ratecard>('http://localhost:8080//shipmentRate/' + id)
            .toPromise();
}
```

### Example 1

But if you want to perform some actions before returning it, you can then use `async-await`-

```js
async getSelectedRatecard(id: number): Promise<Ratecard> {
    const data = await this.http
        .get<Ratecard>('http://localhost:8080//shipmentRate/' + id)
        .toPromise();
    
    // Just an example of some data manipulation before returning
    data.foo = 'bar';
    return data;
}
```

### Example 2

Another example can be something like-

```js
export class Ratecard {

    carrierId: number;
    ucarrierName: string;
    customsClearanceCosts: number;
    flegtSurcharge: number;
    hsCodeCharge: number;
    provisionForPrePaidDutiesFactor: number;
    prepaidCustomsDuty: number;
    deliveryOrder: number;
    inspectionCharges: number;
    lsps20feet: number;
    lsps40feet: number;
    lastmileCtvrede: number;
    ocmFee: number

    foo: string;

    constructor(data?: any) {
        data = data || {};
        this.carrierId = data.carrierId;
        this.ucarrierName = data.ucarrierName;
        // Same for other properties
    }

    doFooBar() {
        this.foo = 'bar';
    }
}
```

```js
async getSelectedRatecard(id: number): Promise<Ratecard> {
    const data = await this.http
        .get<Ratecard>('http://localhost:8080//shipmentRate/' + id)
        .toPromise();

    const rateCard = new Ratecard(data);
    rateCard.doFooBar();
    return rateCard;
}
```

Comment: For option 2: I already use async and await  in the actual http get request in the service class. Is it also necessary to do the same in the setCarrier method? And how do these options make sure selectedRatecard is of type Ratecard?

Comment: Used option 2 and it worked for me! Angular keeps amazing me. Thanks.

Comment: @KaiHoogenhoud I updated the answer and added code improvement that you can apply.